# Multiple music file in document directory in iOS device

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

I am developing an application in iPhone .This application need to store 3 music file (.mp3) to iOS device (the files are from a webserver). The downloading  function working perfectly (Using ASIHTTPrRequest). Some time the music saving not working perfectly, that means I am using a checking before the music file go to music player.

```
playpath=@"/Users/company/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/3D5AD723-F18E-4F44-B3CB-FAEF2EA4963B/Documents/329/25-06-2012/330217/work25-06-2012330217.mp3"

 NSFileManager*fileM=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
if([fileM isReadableFileAtPath:playpath])
    {

     }
```

The playpath (directory path) change with each downloading. some time the downloading paths playing the music and some time this not playing ie this path can not satisfied the above condition .

My questions are

1. What is reason for the above problem?
2. What is the exact functionality of isReadableFileAtPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of explicitly writing out the file path, have the device find the path for you. Here's what I do:

```
- (NSString*) saveFilePath: (NSString *) add
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filename = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:add];
    return filename;
}
```

Add this to whatever class needs to save or load data. Then you'll be able to get the location of your file with:

```
[self saveFilePath:@"Name of file you want to load or write to"]
```

Comment: Thank For for your replay. I have created the path with the same code you suggested.My situation is saving '3' mp3 files in IOS device.So the first time save the file1 to ios device and playing perfectly,when save the second file(file2),the first file can not play due to isReadableFileAtPath. Plz help me its urgent.

Comment: Don't use `isReadableFileAtPath`. The class reference specifically says not to predicate behavior based on this method. Saving multiple music files should not be a problem unless you're saving them to the same place; make sure you're not using the same file name.

Comment: Thank you for your replay.I am using different path for different file.I have one question regarding the document directory , i used 3 or more times NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); and access the zeroth location and appending a string(FilesString) to this.This executing 2, 3 times after saving the first file to documentto file, this process has any issue for saving multiple files?

Comment: No, I use that method to access multiple files all the time.

Comment: Thank you for your replay.I got the exact result.